# Adding Font color and No fill to a sub routine

Tags: vba, excel

hopefully a quick fix on this one. I have a sub routine that I am using to amend the column sizes for all the sheets in a workbook which works absolutely fine but I wanted to add to this sub so that it will change the font color black for all cells within my ranges and remove any fill color from them also. I have written the code below but it doesn't seem to perform the way I want. Any ideas as to how I can correct this would be awesome!

```
Sub forEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Opens new workbook for formatting
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\XNEID\Desktop\Test MPAN Destination 
Folder\Shell_MPANs_Test1.xlsx"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Call resizingColumns(ws)
Next

End Sub

Sub resizingColumns(ws As Worksheet)
With ws
    .Range("A1:BB1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A2:BB2", Range("A2:BB2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack
    Range("A2:BB2", Range("A2:BB2").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest defining a last row (by working up from the bottom), and you omitted the dots necessary for your With statement

```
Sub resizingColumns(ws As Worksheet)

Dim n As Long

With ws
    n = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:BB1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("A2:BB" & n).Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Range("A2:BB" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. It worked an absolute treat.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to fully qualify the cell's object
2. Work with variables. See how I have used it to find the last row
3. Avoid the use of `.Select`

Is this what you are trying?

```
With ws
    .Columns("A:BB").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("A2:BB" & lrow)
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End Withh
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Select` and `ActiveWorkbook`. Instead, simply reference the ranges directly. Try this:

```
Sub forEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

'Opens new workbook for formatting
Set wb = Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\XNEID\Desktop\Test MPAN Destination 
Folder\Shell_MPANs_Test1.xlsx"

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    Call resizingColumns(ws)
Next

End Sub

Sub resizingColumns(ws As Worksheet)

With ws
    .Range("A1:BB1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("A2:BB" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Range("A2:BB" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You missed a DOT in `Range("A2:BB2").End(xlDown)` :D